# Capybara can't find svg element when using ID

Tags: ruby, capybara

The following element is on the page:

```
<use xlink:href="pending">
 <svg id="pending">
```

Using this: `page.should have_css('svg', :id => 'pending', :count => 1)`

Or this: `page.should have_css('svg[id="pending"]', :count => 1)`

Is returning no matches.

I have tried: `page.should have_css('svg', :count => 1)`

Which does return matches, but what i need to find is the specific element with the ID of "pending".

Comment: Does the `svg` have any contents so it has size on the page? If it doesn't have size it's going to be considered non-visible

Answer (score 0):

How about using `has_selector`? Since your ID's should be unique across the whole document, no `count` should be necessary.

```rb
page.should have_selector('#pending')
```

[has_selector? docs](https://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_selector%3F-instance_method)

Comment: `Have_selector` is the same as `have_css` since `have_selector` defaults to :css selector type, so this isn’t going to make any difference and it doesn’t sound like it’s failing due to `count`

Comment: @ThomasWalpole good point. I'm not sure this is the answer. It does give the OP what they asked for (last sentence), although I'm not sure that's what they want.